# How to fix the "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:0X80070002)" error in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

i trying to create a new  project in visual studio .it give some error

please give me some suggestions.....[image]

i don't know this happen.
i am trying to reinstall and again same error is coming .

i try this cant work ...

Comment: What is all that extra info you provided after the sentence "i am trying to reinstall and again same error is coming ."?

Comment: checking the files present or not.

Comment: Did you try googling this?

Comment: s sir ....but i cant get the solution rightly.

Comment: i got it sir......
Simply Uninstall the Nuget package from

Tools-->Extentions and updates-->(Search Nuget) then Uninstall this Nuget version

and Restart the visual studio.

After that need to add nuget package like this procedure and restart the visual studio.

Now it works....

Answer (score 11):

Try 1 first if not other one

1. Go to `Extentions and updates` then Search `Nuget` and uninstall it,
   restart visual studio,  again install  `Nuget` then again restart.
   you should be able to create your new project.
2. Repair your Visual Studio 2013 or 2015

Comment: Oddly enough it turned out to be Nuget being screwed up with the new Web Tools update. That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 8):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Express Web and had the same problem. I searched a lot for solutions and none of these worked:

- Reinstall Nuget for Visual Studio 2015
- Replace Nuget for Visual Studio 2015 with the former Nuget
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Modify/Delete IISExpress applicationhost.config file
- Reinstall IISExpress

The only thing that solved it was a **Repair-install** of Visual Studio:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Enter `appwiz.cpl` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Right-click the entry "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web" and click "Repair"
- Be patient...

**Note:** This is going to reinstall all packages that you have uninstalled, because you weren't needing them (eg. Microsoft SQL Server Native Client).

Comment: Run Visual Studio 2016 as Admin fixed a project issue that was created with .NET4 in Visual Studio 2012 a few years ago. Had to run as Admin seems to have fixed the error on application properties

Answer (score 4):

Go to: VS2013->Tools->Extensions and Updates->Online Search for NuGet and install. Fixed my problem in 2013 REL

Comment: This solution also worked for Visual Studio 2015 Community

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem when creating a .NET core project in VS 2015, and it's resolved by repairing .NET Core. The possible reason is, my .NET core was installed associated with VS community version, but later I uninstall VS community and reinstall professional version, but .NET Core was not uninstalled with community version uninstall. After repairing .NET core from control panel, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error using VS community 2017 (and previous), when trying to open a .cs file, or trying to open project properties.
All that on a fresh VS install on a fresh Windows 10 install...

I found 2 solutions:

Start VS as admin (which is not a good choice, and may prevent debugging drag&drop into your app).

or better:

Change security settings of your %temp% folder to "everyone - full control". :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Nuget package manager from Tools-> Extensions and Updates -> online-> and search 'Nuget package manager' from search bar and click install.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Andriy Svyryd:

Modifying Visual Studio 2015 installation and unchecking Microsoft Web Developer Tools
Deleting C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\DNX folder that was left from a previous version of the tools.
Deleting %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
Deleting %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
Running repair on the preview2 tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the relevent components installed along with Visual Studio?

I was getting this error when trying to add a new Axure Mobile Services project.  Knowing how long repairing Visual Studio takes, I hoped to avoid that.

What fixed it for me was opening up Programs and Features, and selecting "Modify" Visual Studio rather than "Repair".

I'm not sure if there was an error in a previous installation that I didn't notice, but Web Tools wasn't selected in the installed components.  After selecting that, installing, and restarting my computer, I no longer got the error when trying to add a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I try to create ASP.NET MVC 4 web application in VS 2012.

To resolve this issue In VS 2012 click on Tools (menu)>>Extensions and Updates (menu item) >> in the Extensions and Updates window click on Updates menu.

Install pending updates for VS 2012 and also for Nuget.

Restart the VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

My version of the problem was caused by VS extensions running in the background.
My solution: disable non-critical extension "Extension" -> "Manage Extensions" -> "Installed" -> disable: "Visual Studio IntelliCode", and also disable other extensions not currently in use.
-> restart VS