# .Net 4.6 starting project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with starting ASP .NET 4.6 project. When I choose WebForm and then click ok I see below error window:

[image]

In English, the error message says:

> File specified cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

And I have nothing in my solution. Even MasterPage doesn't appear. What can I do with this issue?

Comment: Your error message is not in English language which is the default language of communication on this website. Can you please translate the error message in English for the readers?

Comment: Also, as much as I understand you are just trying to create a new ASP .Net web form project by selecting ASP .Net project template. Are you?

Comment: Translation: `File specified cannot be found`. Google, finds this [troubleshooting guide, helpfully translated into Polish](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms165678(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Yes exactly, if I create project in 3.5 or even 4 there is no problem. Only when I'm trying to create project with Master Page 4+ there are some missing file when I open solution

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem when I have got corrupted .net framework installation.

Try to reinstall it. also running visual studio with repair option could help.

Seems like configuration problem or system issue.

Comment: I've already reinstalled Visual Studio and .net 4.6 framework but still doesn't work. I'm working with VS 2015 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you clear VS cache ? C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Comment: also is there anything interesting in your activitylog.xml ? C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml

Comment: Yes I did but nothing changed

Comment: Also in this thread their suggest to reinstall nuget through Extensions and Updates: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299341/the-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified-in-visual-studio-exception-from-hres)